# How do you make an Obish Translator on Python?

Tags: python

I have to make a translator on Python that converts an English word into the obish translation. Obish basically means that there is an -ob before the vowels in the word. Can anyone help me with this problem? This is the code I have so far and it is far from perfect or done, but it is the most I can do at the moment. Please help!!!! Thank you.

```
def convert(userInput):
    english = userInput.getText()
    obish = 'ob'
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = english.lower()
        x = word[0]
        if x == "a" or x == "e" or x == "i" or x == "o" or x == "u":
            obWord = word + ob
            print (obWord)
        else:
            print ('')
    else:
        print ('empty')
```

Comment: Can you remove all the code that's not related to the problem? None of the code regarding mouse clicks and windows is relevant.

Comment: Why do you only check the first letter of the word?

Comment: There's no variable `original`. Should that be `english`? Why are you only checking for a vowel in the first letter of the word?

Comment: `ob` is supposed to go before each vowel. You're putting it at the end of the word. Why?

Comment: I'm gonna take a shot in the dark and say you're new to Python. Email me at ChrisNguyen180@gmail.com and I'll be happy to help teach you Python (or anything else, really)

Answer (score 1):

Given a message, you can try this:

```
english = userInput.getText()

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

new_message = ''.join("ob"+i if i.lower() in vowels else i for i in english)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression replacement will do it:

```
import re
obish = re.sub(r'[aeiou]', r'ob\g<0>', english, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```